# Azure SQL Database - change user permissions on a read-only database for cross-database queries

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

We use Azure SQL Database, and therefore had to jump through some hoops to get cross-database queries set up.  We achieved this following this great article:  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/cross-database-query-in-azure-sql-database/ba-p/369126  Things are working great for most of our databases.

The problem comes in for one of our databases which is read-only.  The reason it's read-only is b/c it is being synced from another Azure SQL Server to derive its content.  This is being achieved via the Geo-Replication function in Azure SQL Database.  When attempting to run the query `GRANT SELECT ON [RemoteTable] TO RemoteLogger` as seen in the linked article, I of course get the error "Failed to update because the database is read-only."

I have been trying to come up with a workaround for this.  It appears user permissions are one of the things that do NOT sync as part of the geo-replication, as I've created this user and granted the SELECT permission on the origin database, but it doesn't carry over.

Has anyone run into this or something similar and found a workaround/solution?  Is it safe/feasible to temporarily set the database to read/write, update the permission, then put it back to read-only?  I don't know if this is even possible - I was told by one colleague that they think it will throw an error along the lines of "this database can't be set to read/write b/c it's syncing from another database..."

Comment: I do feel it needs to be stated that if you are using Azure SQL Databases and need to have cross database queries, you probably shouldn't be using an Azure SQL Database and should be, instead, using a SQL Server hosted in Azure. It's by design that the databases are contained databases, and performance for "cross database" queries in Azure SQL Databases can be quite poor.

Comment: I understand that, and I have no control over that.  That isn't really helpful in this context.  Cross-database queries are working perfectly in all other cases aside from this one read-only database.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a work-around:  Create a remote connection to the database on the ORIGIN server.  So simple, yet it escaped me until now.  Everything working great now.